Computing $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2 + 1}$ via contour integration
I am trying to compute the sum $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2 + 1}$$ via contour integration.
I have considered the function $$f(z) = \frac{\pi e^{i \pi z}\cot(\pi z)}{z^2 + 1}$$ along the square $\gamma_N$ with vertices at $(N + 1/2)(\pm 1 \pm i)$. By ML inequality, the integral around each edge tends to zero as $N\to \infty$, and thus $\int_{\gamma_N} f(z) dz \to 0$ as $N\to\infty$.
Letting $N\to\infty$, $f$ has simple poles at $z = n$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and at $z = -i,i$. Thus, by Residue Theorem, $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\text{Res}_{z=n}f(z) + \text{Res}_{z=i}f(z) + \text{Res}_{z=-i}f(z) = 0$.
I found that $\text{Res}_{z=n}f(z) = \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2 + 1}, \text{Res}_{z=i} = \frac{\pi e^{-\pi}\cot(i \pi)}{2i}, \text{Res}_{z=-i}f(z) = - \frac{\pi e^{\pi}\cot(-i\pi)}{2i}$ and using $\coth,\cot$ relations found that $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2 + 1} = \frac{\pi}{2}\coth(\pi)(e^{\pi} + e^{-\pi})$$ but this is incorrect
(Note: from this I could find the sum I want given that the function I am summing over is even).
Where have I gone wrong?
EDIT: I just noticed that $|e^{ i\pi z}|$ is not always equal to $1$, so I'm assuming this blows up on the contour somewhere and so my integral isn't actually equal to zero.
